# Python selenium Replace empty class

Tags: python, selenium

I recently started coding a program where I want to scrape a betting website
But I stumbled onto a problem.
Some odds are empty so there is a different class name
Is there a way I can tell selenium to print a zero instead of skipping the class?
to keep things in order I need to scrape the odds and the zero in order
for example:
(first row)
1.01
2.4
empty --> 0
(second row)
1.3
2.3
etc...

This is the code I already wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time
import pickle
import re

options = Options()
options.headless = False
web = 'https://sports.bwin.be/nl/sports/live/voetbal-4?fallback=false'
path = r'C:\Users\Senne\Desktop\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)
driver.get(web)
driver.maximize_window()

Cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')))
Cookies.click()

#for Team in Teams:
#    print(Team.text)

Odds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-view"]/ms-live/ms-live-event-list/div/ms-grid/ms-event-group/ms-event/div/div/ms-option-group[1]')

for odd in Odds:
        #if not Odds:
        #        Odds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('offline.option-indicator')
        #else:
        #        print("0")
        print(odd.text)

driver.quit()
```

I thaught

```
   if not Odds:
           Odds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('offline.option-indicator')
    else:
            print("0")
```

would help but between every 3 odds I get a 0

example :
0
4.10
3.40
1.75
0
2.10
2.95
3.30
0
101.00
31.00
0
4.60
2.70
2.05